# Database migration from new YAML in Doctrine

Tags: database, migration, doctrine, yaml

I have to add a new column and a new table to my database but i dont have access to shell of my server. I changed my YAML file. How can i tell doctrine to "migrate models and database to changed yaml"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doctrine_Core class has a lot of static methods like generateMigrationsFromDiff(), which you can use in case you dont't have access to cli tasks  (see full api at http://www.doctrine-project.org/Doctrine_Core/1_2). I am not sure that it's exactly what you need, so don't forget to make backup :)